# Why does my website load to the extreme left?

Tags: web, position

When ever my website loads I can only see half of it unless I scroll to the left. I tried centering it by putting `background-position: center left` and it works. But when I zoom out/in it moves to the left/right. Anyone have solutions?

Thanks

Comment: You may have to provide some code example to show the problem before we can suggest solutions.

Comment: Using the margin:auto attribute is superior and preferable as Ryan pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I use something similar to the below code for example, if we have a div named wrapper, and width 960px, use the following code.

```
#wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   position: relative;
   margin: auto;
}
```

margin: auto; will automatically center your webpage